# Error in clipping data using Earh Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to clip data values equal to one and convert them to vector in earth engine. Anyone have advice on how to do this please?

```js
var Polygon = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[64.92750226740498, 41.287279412206004],
          [64.92750226740498, 38.52365122708777],
          [68.75074445490498, 38.52365122708777],
          [68.75074445490498, 41.287279412206004]]], null, false);


var collection1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 20).filterBounds(Polygon).filterDate('2018-04-15', '2018-04-30');
var image1 = collection1.mean();

var ndvi1 = image1.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).lt(0.3);

var collection2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 20).filterBounds(Polygon).filterDate('2018-05-01', '2018-05-15');
var image2 = collection2.mean();
var ndvi2 = image2.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).lt(0.3);

var collection3 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 20).filterBounds(Polygon).filterDate('2018-08-15', '2018-08-31');
var image3 = collection3.mean();
var ndvi3 = image3.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).gt(0.4);

var collection4 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 20).filterBounds(Polygon).filterDate('2018-05-01', '2018-05-15');
var image4 = collection4.mean();
var ndvi4 = image4.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).gt(0.4);

var collection5 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 20).filterBounds(Polygon).filterDate('2018-06-15', '2018-06-30');
var image5 = collection5.mean();
var ndvi5 = image5.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).lt(0.3);

var collection6 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 20).filterBounds(Polygon).filterDate('2018-07-01', '2018-07-15');
var image6 = collection6.mean();
var ndvi6 = image6.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).lt(0.3);


var cotton = (ndvi1).and(ndvi2).and(ndvi3);
var wheat = (ndvi4).and(ndvi5).and(ndvi6);

var cottonViz = {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['#FFFFFF00', 'red']};
var ndviMasked = cotton.updateMask(cotton.gte(0.5));
Map.addLayer(ndviMasked, cottonViz, 'Cotton');

var wheatViz = {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['#FFFFFF00', 'blue']};
var ndviMasked = wheat.updateMask(wheat.gte(0.5));
Map.addLayer(ndviMasked, wheatViz, 'wheat');


// Show original
Map.addLayer(cotton, null, 'Polygon');
Map.addLayer(wheat, null, 'Polygon');


// Image projection
var proj1 = cotton.projection()
var proj2 = wheat.projection()

// Mask out pixels with values not equal to zero
var mask1 = cotton.neq(0);
var masked1 = cotton.updateMask(mask1).neq(0);

var mask2 = wheat.neq(0);
var masked2 = wheat.updateMask(mask2).neq(0);


// get pixel's connectedness
var conn1 = masked1.connectedPixelCount(2).reproject(proj1)
var conn2 = masked2.connectedPixelCount(2).reproject(proj2)

// Mask where pixels surrounded by zeros have a value of one
var one_around1 = conn1.eq(1)
var one_around2 = conn2.eq(1)
// Show
Map.addLayer(one_around1, null, 'pixels rounded by one')
Map.addLayer(one_around2, null, 'pixels rounded by one')

// Convert the cotton and wheat to vectors.
var list = ee.List(['cotton', 'wheat'])
//
var cotton = cotton.reduceToVectors({
  geometry: Polygon,
  geometryType: 'polygon',
  eightConnected: false,
  labelProperty: 'cotton1',
  scale: 300
});
//
var wheat = wheat.reduceToVectors({
  geometry: Polygon,
  geometryType: 'polygon',
  eightConnected: false,
  labelProperty: 'wheat1',
  scale: 300
});
```

Comment: Hi! In the future please be sure to: 1) Include a little more info in the body of the question to provide context; 2) format your script as a code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when clipping two layers using any technology, you need to make sure that there are features overlapping. In your code:

```
// get pixel's connectedness
    var conn1 = masked1.connectedPixelCount(2).reproject(proj1)
    var conn2 = masked2.connectedPixelCount(2).reproject(proj2)
```

It seams that you are setting 2 different projections for two layers that are supposed to be overlapping. Try setting the same  projection either proj1 or proj2 on the 2 layers.

Also, in your code I cannot see what you are clipping and where you are clipping the data.

If you are looking for a ready made solution for your project I suggest you search throughout the web before posting here. I have come across an example that might be what you are looking for where areas are clipped then converted to vectors using Earth Engine.

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_reduce_to_vectors

I hope this helps.